# Failed to apply plugin class FlutterPlugin in flutter applicartion

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i am trying to build flutter app in windows but i faced this

```
Failed to apply plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'.
   > Could not find implementation class 'com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin' for plugin 
'com.android.application' specified in jar:file:/C:/Users/Hassan%20Hallak/.gradle/caches/jars-
9/04cdd82c2d7186a6d1a857203ac3fa48/gradle-7.3.0.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.android.application.properties.

>
```

every thing is ok with flutter doctor
what is the problem

Comment: What Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin versions are  you using?

Comment: i fix this issue you can see me answer

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue by this steps :

1. update flutter to last version 3.10.5
2. user last android studio with last gradle 8.0
3. Edit **distributionUrl** to  8.0 in this path

gradle->wrapper-> gradel-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl =https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip